# How to configure SparkPost in Laravel 1.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use SparkPost mail server to send emails in Laravel.

When I try to send one email I get an error:

```
"Client error: `POST https:\/\/api.sparkpost.com\/api\/v1\/transmissions` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n{ \"errors\": [ { \"message\": \"Invalid domain\", \"description\": \"No sending domain specified\", \"code\": \"7001\" } ] }\n"
```

My configuration is:

`services.php`

```
'sparkpost' => [
        'secret' => "key-api",
    ],
```

`mail.php`:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'sparkpost'),
```

Comment: Er, Laravel *1.5*?

Comment: I use Laravel 1.5.3

Comment: Are you sure it's not just *5.3*, the latest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is "No sending domain specified". You have to add one sending domain.

[image: Account->Sending domains]

Comment: I have sending domains in this section. May be I must to set this in configurtion file?

Comment: I use the next configuration in the .env file (I use sparkpost with SMTP):

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sparkpostmail.com
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=SMTP_Injection
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Then I use the  Mail::send function: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail

Answer (score 0):

I setup SparkPost with my site. You have to install guzzle if your sending over http `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` which is the default for Laravel SparkPost driver...at least it is for Laravel 5.4. Then in your env file you have to set

```
SPARKPOST_SECRET=

MAIL_DRIVER=sparkpost

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=you@your-sparkpost-sending-domain

MAIL_FROM_NAME=your-website-name (This is the from line in the email inbox)
```

The `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` is the address you set in your SparkPost sending domains.

I know this is an old post. But I found it while I was looking for an answer to the same question.